# How do I create a timestamp from a separate date string and time string in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

I need some assistance.

The code uses a `date()` function to acquire the *report date*, while the *availability times* are manually entered by users. The *availability times* are then compared to a *static time* in order to show whether the process was complete on time.

This process works perfectly if all processes run on the same day; however inaccurate reporting occurs when the process completes before midnight of the previous day. This is where I need some assistance.

I need to take the time string, which is set as `H:i` format, and merge it with the date string, which is set as `yyyy/mm/dd`. Once this is performed, I can compare it to the *report date stamp* to get proper reporting.

Comment: sample input and expected output?

Comment: if they are strings, you simply concatenate them `$YmdHi = $Ymd . $Hi`

Comment: Sample code probably with some sample values? Also concatenate the strings as Gordon suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

concatenation operator in PHP is a dot, `"."`
and you can always concatenate whatever date with whatever time

```
$date = "2012/01/04";
$time = "22:12";
$datetime = $date." ".$time;
```

then you can compare the latter variable with whatever datetime of the same format

Answer (score 4):

Concat the two strings respectively, date and time then insert the result string into [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$date = '2012/06/15';
$time = ' 10:33';
echo strtotime($date.$time)
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might point you in the right direction:

```
<?php

$date = "2013/01/04";
$time = "16:58"; // I'm assuming you meant H:i format (not capital I as in your question).

$timestamp = strtotime($date." ".$time);

echo $timestamp; // 1357318680

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I wrote my question in Word first to make sure I didn't make mistakes. Apparently Word felt the i should have been capitalized. I will pay more attention going forward.

All submissions were very helpful. As result, I have gotten a little closer to my intended outcome. Thank you.